# MySQL / DBServer

Tags: windows, installation, mysql

I'm trying to match services running on Windows servers using the executable path returned by WMI.

I'm getting MySQL through a path like

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqld.exe
```

I also see paths like

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\DBServer\bin\mysqld.exe
```

- Is the latter path referring to standard MySQL ?
- Is it a component of another piece of software altogether?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Windows Command Line and run the Following

```
cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin"
mysqld --version
cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\DBServer\bin"
mysqld --version
```

These should return something like

```
mysqld  Ver 5.5.37-log for Win64 on x86 (MySQL Community Server (GPL))
```

You will see which version of MySQL is which.

As for `C:\Program Files\MySQL\DBServer\bin`, it had to be a custom installation to name the folder different from what the Windows MSI installer would normally name it. Perhaps the MSI allowed for the new name. Maybe someone hacked it.

What you should do is open the following:

- Control Panel
- Administrative Tools
- Services
- Scroll Down and Look for MySQL
- Right Click on MySQL
- Click on Properties

A windows pops up. In the middle of it, look for `Path to Excutable`. You will see what binary executable is being used by the installed MySQL service.

Doing the custom install by hand is not that hard.

Let's say MySQL 5.0 in the current MySQL Server and you want to enable DBServer instead

You do the following in the Windows Command Line as Administrator:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin"
mysqld --remove
cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\DBServer\bin"
mysqld --install
```

That would have been one way the custom install had been done.